# Translating a song lyric

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

I'm trying to translate the main line "どうして君を傷つけたのだろう" from Yasushi Nakanishi's song of the same name. Can this be "Why would I possibly hurt you ?" Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it means "Why did I hurt you" or "I wonder why I hurt you", meaning this person actually hurt someone and is regretting what he did.